# How to convert \t into TAB character?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString* abc = @"\u003ca\\tb\\tc\u003e";
```

How can I convert it to `<a  b  c>`

Comment: What is the question? `\t` actually is the TAB character (ASCII 9). `\u003a` is `<` and `\u003e` is `>`. So, what do you want to do?

Comment: What do you mean convert? \t is the TAB character. If it doesn't show up that way it's the problem of the display format. E.g. HTML collapses all whitespace sequences into one space in most text.

Comment: Just omit the extra backslash before `\t`?

Comment: Don't use the doubled \\.  That causes the string to contain `\t` rather than the tab character, because \\ means "backslash character".  Just use `\t`, without the extra \.

Comment: And if the string is arriving that way, and you have no control over it, replace occurrences of "\\t" with "\t".

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal tab, you should use "\t". And for "<" or ">" unicode character pass its hexadecimal value and log it by character specifier (%c) as i used below. It must work for you as I have tried in my xcode and it worked for me.

```
NSString * requiredStrg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c a\tb\tc %c",0x3c,0x3e];
NSLog(@"%@",requiredStrg);
```